# Can't install Pillow on server

Tags: python, django, pip, python-imaging-library

Porting my Django application to 3.3 and Django 1.6b2, I'm currently installing on the server all the depedencies that works locally.
It seems like I can't install Pillow and neither can I install anyjson. Here are the errors I get :
For Anyjson :

```
error: in 'ext_modules' option (extension 'bson._cbson'), 'sources' must be present and must be a list of source filenames
```

For Pillow :

```
error: in 'ext_modules' option (extension 'PIL._imaging'), 'sources' must be present and must be a list of source filenames
```

Could someone help me please ? =)

Comment: Install `freetype2` library (package name depends on the server), then `PIL`, then `pillow`.

Comment: Pill before Pillow? what?

Comment: @lalo http://stackoverflow.com/a/8773615/771848 :)

Comment: @alecxe Pilow [documentation](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow) say: **PIL and Pillow currently cannot co-exist in the same environment. If you want to use Pillow, please remove PIL first.**

Comment: Pillow is a fork of Pil why should I install them both ?
Problem solved anyway, removing distribute and setuptools and reinstalling them solved the problem. oO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing and reinstalling distribute and setuptools.
Don't know why but worked.

Comment: will you please explain how'd you uninstalled it ??

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstalling `distribute` didn't work but removing it for `setuptools` made it work.